# Get "Day" From This Formatted Timestamp In Javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I'm working with Javascript within Google Sheets, and I'm having trouble converting or parsing a formatted timestamp, to ultimately extract the day as a numerical value.

My code:

```
var shopifyTimestamp = "2019-05-18 13:21:17 +0100";

var date = new Date(shopifyTimestamp);

Logger.log(date.getDay());
```

The output:

```
[19-06-10 17:40:56:107 BST] NaN
```

My goal is to extract the day number, for example, "18" from that timestamp.

However, it doesn't seem to convert it. I suspect my timestamp isn't in the correct format for the `date()` function, so it's about creating a function to parse it.

Hopefully, you can help me with that! :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The date object has a method like this for getting the day of the month as a number (1-31).

```
date.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

`18` is date.

```js
var shopifyTimestamp ="2019-05-18 13:21:17 +0100";
var date = new Date(shopifyTimestamp);

console.log(date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `Date` constructor supports [ISO 8601 date strings](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Without using any libraries, you can do something like this:

```js
var shopifyTimestamp = "2019-05-18 13:21:17 +0100";

// will produce `2019-05-18T13:21:17+0100`
var isoDate = shopifyTimestamp.slice(0, 10)
    + 'T' + shopifyTimestamp.slice(11, 19)
    + shopifyTimestamp.slice(20);

var date = new Date(isoDate);

console.log(date.getDate()); // 18
```

Also note that you're looking for `date.getDate()`, rather than `date.getDay()`. The latter returns the numerical date of the week.